# using nuxt 3 useFetch in layouts

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm new to the nuxt community.

I have a problem in my layout that is being used in different pages

my pages:

`/pages /pages/[category] -- index.vue -- [id].vue`

in the index.vue I make use of a layout in this I use useFetch to get the posts according to the [category], the posts are displayed in a sidebar

when I click on the post in my sidebar it enters [id].vue, it also uses the same layout but whenever I change [id] it makes the call to the server again

Is there something that avoids making the call if I'm in the same category when changing the [id] post

tried with onMounted and onBeforeRouteUpdate

Comment: If I understand correctly, `useFetch` is inside the layout component right?
I think that's the problem, being a call made from a wrapper component it will be called every time you change course

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition to check the route name using [useRoute](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route#useroute) and then make an API call. Since pages/[category]/index.vue and pages/[id].vue are two different routes with their own unique route names.

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const myCategories = ref([]);

//you can check exact route details from vue devtools extension's routes section.
if(route.name == 'pages-category'){
   const { data:allCategories } = await useFetch('/api/get-categories/');
   myCategories.value = allCategories;
}
</script>
```